# React / Webpack / Express Issues when rendering server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm trying to implement server side rendering into my existing React/Redux app. After several failed attempts I think I'm almost there but i'm running into a few issues. I'm fairly new to React/Redux/Express/Webpack so apologies if i've made any stupid errors!

**Issue 1 - window is not defined**

As I'm using Redux I need to keep track of initial state and load this into my application. Inside `server/index.js` I'm getting the initial state from the store and storing it on window using `window.__initialData__ = ${serialize(initialData)}`.

Server code is below:

```js
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';

import routes from 'routes/routes';
import store from 'store';
import AppContainer from 'containers/app-container/app-container';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('static'));

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  const promises = routes.reduce((accumulator, route) => {
    if (matchPath(req.url, route) && route.component && route.component.initialAction) {
      accumulator.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction())));
    }

    return accumulator;
  }, []);

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      const context = {};
      const markup = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <AppContainer />
          </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
      );

      const initialData = store.getState();
      res.send(`
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <title>W Combinator</title>
            <script src='/static/assets/app.js' defer></script>
            <script src='/static/assets/vendor.js' defer></script>
            <script>window.__initialData__ = ${serialize(initialData)}</script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div id='root'>${markup}</div>
          </body>
        </html>
      `);
    })
    .catch(next);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening');
});
```

When I create my store in the front end I try and access this window variable like so `const initialState = window.__initialData__;`. The problem I am getting is an error in terminal is being thrown saying window is not defined. I've tried to fix this by setting `process.env.BROWSER` in Webpack but it doesn't seem to work.

Webpack code is below:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');

const basePath = path.join(__dirname, 'app');
const distPath = path.join(__dirname, 'static/assets');

const browserConfig = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    vendor: './app/client/vendor.js',
    app: './app/client/index.jsx'
  },
  output: {
    path: distPath,
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['static']),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Default Template',
      template: './app/client/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css'
    }),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    new StyleLintPlugin({
      files: ['app/**/*.scss'],
      syntax: 'scss'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.BROWSER': JSON.stringify(true)
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(`${basePath}/client`),
      path.resolve(`${basePath}/server`),
      path.resolve('node_modules/')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [basePath]
      },
      {
        test: /\.global\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: basePath,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [basePath]
            }
          }]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.scss$/],
        include: basePath,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[local]-__-[hash:base64:5]', 'postcss-loader', {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [basePath]
            }
          }]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          'svg-sprite-loader',
          'svgo-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        include: basePath,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        include: basePath,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const serverConfig = {
  entry: './app/server/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: basePath,
    filename: 'server.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [basePath]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.BROWSER': JSON.stringify(false)
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(`${basePath}/client`),
      path.resolve(`${basePath}/server`),
      path.resolve('node_modules/')
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = [browserConfig, serverConfig];
```

**Issue 2 - Unexpected token <**

If I manually set initial state i'm able to get the page to render server side, the problem i'm having with this is that I'm getting a console error saying `Unexpected token <`. I've done some reading and my guess is I'm missing some kind of config setting in my express server but I can't see to get it to work.

**Issue 3 - Error: Child compilation failed:**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./app/client/index.ejs
        Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory app/client/index.ejs
```

If I manually set initial state and ignore the error above then I can see my content rendered on the page without any errors in terminal. When I however make a change to a file in my app and save then I get the above error appear in terminal and it doesn't compile. The error states it seems to be looking for an `index.ejs` file which it can't seem to find. I'm not currently using any templating engine in my app and i'm just serving up a static `index.html` file as you can see in the webpack config above.

Again my guess is I haven't set something up properly or I've missed a config option, i've spent a while trying to fix these but can't seen to identify the root cause.

If anyone knows how to fix these then help would be greatly appreciated!

Babelrc

```
  {
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
 }
```

**EDIT**

Issue 1 I've managed to resolve, I wasn't creating my store correctly inside the server, adding this `const store = configureStore();` after the `app.get(*...` and tweaking my store setup slightly fixed this. For reference I used [this](https://github.com/cassiozen/ReactCasts/tree/master/episode13) link to help with that setup.

**EDIT**

Issue 2 was caused by the JS files not being served as static files. `app.use(express.static('./static/assets'))` fixed this.

Comment: Can you add your babel config?

Comment: @imcvampire added

Comment: its tragic that no one has been able to give you a definitive answer @woolm110. I have been struggling with Issue 2. This is on Heroku and Heroku is just giving me 200 status ok all the way, but the app is not rendering in the browser at all.